# Laravel: Login with Auth driver, but without password

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay, so to keep it simple I have a `users` table, and a `User` model. The table contains a unique identifier `com_id` (plus other user info), which I'd like to login with, but no password.

I'd like to log the user in, and be able to access their data via the Auth driver: `Auth::user()->email` etc, but I'm having some problems logging them in.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['com_id' => $com_id]))
{
   dd("successful login");
}
```

With this, I get an error regarding the `UserInterface`, so in my Model I add:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->steam_community_id;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

But what do I do about the password? I can't remove the function since it's required, and I'm not sure what the `getAuthIdentifier` is supposed to refer to?

Any help would be nice.

I could handle this through Sessions, but surely this is possible the "normal" way.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually). You could also use Auth::loginUsingId().

Comment: Think I tried that but it didn't seem to do much, I'll try again though, but would that be the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say the correct way to solve this would be to implement your own auth provider (that extends `UserProviderInterface`) that doesn't care about a password. Laravel ships with a couple of providers: DatabaseUserProvider and EloquentUserProvider, but both assume a hashed password. In fact, even if you create your own auth provider, you have to implement a method that validates the credentials (but these credentials don't have to be password-based), but this method could be what checks the steam community id against an API or something.

As I understand it, `getAuthIdentifier` is used to store the user's id in session (and in remember me scenarios too). So it pretty much just have to be any unique identifier for the user (sounds like your com_id field would do the trick there). `getAuthPassword` does indeed have to return a hashed password, but this is for compatibility with Laravel's hashed-password-assuming `DatabaseUserProvider` and `EloquentUserProvider`, so you can safely implement the method but make it do nothing useful if you were to use your own provider.

However, if you can't really see the point in creating your own provider just to undo the assumptions that Laravel makes, then just implement those methods as above in your User model (unique identifier for `getAuthIdentifier` and blank string or no return value for `getAuthPassword`) and use your own means to retrieve a user from the database and then use `Auth::login($user)` directly to bypass any checking of a password in the traditional sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, got it working after changing a few things (putting the identifier back to normal and return a blank response on the password side :))

Comment: i am also looking to same concept in laravel 5.1 .if you know can you post

Answer (score 7):

To log in user without a password in Laravel 4. You just need to call method `login`.

`Auth::login($user);`

This method will log in your user without any credential check.

If you need to check the credentials in other hand, this method which will check the credentials.

`Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true);`

Comment: Thanks this works, but what happens if a user changes their password from a different computer or how will the user's session expire in this case.

Answer (score 5):

This is a hack and may help in the case of debugging.

In Laravel 5 refer the file `/vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php`
and its member function `validateCredentials`. Here they are checking the password is existing against the user (email, username or what ever). You can simply `return true` if you want to bypass the credential checking.

```
    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // return true; // this will bypass the password checking.
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the functions in your models are:

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->steam_community_id;
}

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```

These are mutable and by default, `getAuthIdentifier` the `id` primary key from your `auth` `users` table setup in the `app/config/auth.php` file and you may change the table (also model) for `auth` driver to be used for user authentication. So, if you have `users` table and `User` model then it's fine, make sure the primary key in your users table is `id` and if that's different than `id` then here in this function return that field instead, if it's for example `some_id` then return `some_id` instead.

The `getAuthPassword` method returns the `password` field by default and if you want to change the password field with anything else for example `some_token` then return the `some_token` instead of `password like`return `$this->passwordField;` and here use the `passwordField` as your `password`. This lets you set your password filed, the field you set will be used to authenticate the user.

For password filed, make sure you use a [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) method to `encript` the field when saving.